# how to fix bad seo after being hacked

Tags: seo, wordpress

About a year ago my wordpress website was hacked & some company decided to go nuts and actually do some "SEO" on the various links it created. Some of the pages would show up on google as "payday cash advance" instead of "portfolio".

The issue has been resolved, but now as I've been doing GOOD seo, I've noticed (when checking backlinks) that there are TONS of links still on the internet (mostly broken sites now) that have links to my website with titles like: "get a loan today" and so on.

Is there a way to remove these links ? Can I tell google to ignore them ?

Help !

Comment: I heard that in Google WebMaster there is option of reporting spam links to remove from google search engine , you can check more on this

Comment: I've heard that too, just can't find the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution! Google allows you to "disavow" links! 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en

Super cool! Now I can clean up all this mess...